# How to allow all resources in static folder of spring boot maven using spring security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am creating a app using angular for frontend and spring boot for backend.
I am using spring-boot-security for the security purpose.

Spring boot serves static content from `src/main/resources/static` folder.
I am placing all the contents of angular dist folder here, i.e. all js,css,html produced by `ng build`.

But upon running the app, I keep on getting a 401 unauthorized error.
Here is my `configure()` method:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/login/").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(getJWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
    }
```

If I add `.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()` then the app will load all angular resources correctly but makes the security then useless as all api endpoints are then exposed.

Also I read that `\css,\images,\js` etc. are allowed by default, but here my I just refer to static folder.I also tried moving all the content to a new endpoint, say `/app` by implementing `addResourceHandlers()` method, but then my angular code breaks, since it references all css,jss directly in its href and not behind any folder name.

I am using spring boot 2.1.1 release and most of the answers refer to spring boot  v1, and I am unable to find a soln.

I want to configure spring security to allow access to just all resources under `static` folder. Doing so will allow me to use my angular code without changing all hrefs. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the URL of your statoic sources? Show one example.

Comment: I have placed all my resources in `src/main/resources/static` folder. I access the index.html there by `http://localhost:8080/` itself. When spring security is enabed, I start getting 401 to this URL

Comment: What URL do you use for your static resources, for example, how do you call your CSS files?

Comment: Since the app is angular based, they are called directly like `<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js">`. src always has direct reference to the file.

Comment: Just see it like all required files are present in the same folder, nothing is present in a sub-folder

Comment: The URL is wrong. Instead of `styles.js` it has to be `/js/styles.js`.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?